# HttpPostedFileBase returns Null MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a project in C# with MVC4.
Here my question:

I'm trying to convert a byte[] to HttpPostedFileBase, but it always returns Null (even if the byte[] contains data). Here the code I have:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)        {               
HttpPostedFileBase file = value as HttpPostedFileBase
}
```

That code is part of my IsValid function where I'm validating if the uploaded image is Valid (less than 1MB, just 'jpg' or 'png', etc.).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, add action codes in Controller or add more detail about your problem

Answer (score 2):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div> bla bla
</div>
</form>
?
```

Edit : method="post"

```
+

[HttpPost]
```

plz post your controller code else try this above

Answer (score 2):

With Html helper class you can write it as follows

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Company", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="LogoFileUp" id="LogoFileUp"></span>
}
```

and in Create Post Action you can get value as:

```
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create( HttpPostedFileBase LogoFileUp)
{
   // bla bla ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Elvin's answer you can use a model where you can add dataanotations containing the extensions you want to allow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141%28VS.100%29.aspx

The Model: CompanyModel.cs

```
public class CompanyModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Logo")]
    [File(AllowedFileExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif", ".tiff", ".png" }, MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 30, ErrorMessage = "Invalid File")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase LogoFileUp{ get; set; }

    //you can add other properties if you like, for example companyname
}
```

The View

```
@model CompanyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Company", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LogoFileUp)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LogoFileUp)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LogoFileUp, new { type = "file" })
}
```

The Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CompanyModel company)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //save company ...
    }else{
        return View(company)
    }
}
```